# Solve the differential equation: $y' = 2\left(\frac{y+2}{x+y-1}\right)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation:

$$y' = 2\left(\frac{y+2}{x+y-1}\right)^2$$

I think a substitution is required here to make it linear or separable but my attempt of $y = ux$ does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the aim of obtain something 'linear', consider the change of variables $X=x+a$ and $Y=y+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are chosen in such way that
$$\begin{cases}Y=y+2,\\ X+Y=x+y-1. \end{cases}$$
Then $a=-3$ and $b=2$ and you have a new ODE given by
$$\dfrac{dY}{dX}=2\left(\dfrac{Y}{X+Y}\right)^2$$
and here the change of variables $Z=Y/X$ works.

Answer (score 1):

At page 19 of “DIFFERENTIALGLEICHUNGEN LOSUNGSMETHODEN UND LOSUNGEN” by E. KAMKE (1948), we have the equation typus (c) :

$y’=f\Big(\frac{a x+b y+c}{\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma}\Big)$

Setting $a=0; b=\sqrt{2}; c=2\sqrt{2}$;

$\alpha=1; \beta=1; \gamma=-1$,

$\Delta=-\sqrt{2};$

$x=u+3; y=v-2$,

the equation becomes:

$v’=\frac{2 v^{2}}{(u+v)^{2}}$

Setting

$v=z . u(z);$

$dv=u+z.du$

and

$\frac{dv}{du}= \frac{u}{du}+z=\frac{2 z^{2}}{(z+1)^{2}}$

$\frac{u}{du}=-\frac{ z(1+z^{2}}{(z+1)^{2}}$

After integration:

$LN(u)=-LN(z)-2 \arctan(z)$

$LN(u)+LN\big(\frac{v}{u}\big)+ 2 \arctan\big(\frac{v}{u}\big)=c$

$LN(v)+ 2 \arctan\big(\frac{v}{u}\big)=c$

$LN(y+2)+2\arctan\left(\frac{y+2}{x-3}\right)=c$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mathematica, I found that given the equation
$$ 2 \arctan\left(\frac{3-x}{2+y}\right)+\log(2+y)=c, $$
differentiating and simplifying it gives
$$ y' = 2\left(\frac{y+2}{x+y-1}\right)^2. $$

Comment: How could I methodically get that ?